# Item change event in datasheet mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I have a list with calculated field subtotal. I placed a textbox which will populate total of the subtotal. As I understand, you cannot sum for calculated fields. I used javascript to loop through the list items and get the total  and placed it in the text box. But, the problem is the sum is based on Quantity and the list is in datasheet view so that users can easily change it.

I was thinking to add a item change event in the javascript and make necessary changes so that the text box will get updated with the total each time the Quantity is changed. or even a post back when item is changed.

Can some one suggest a way to do so or the event handler of when an item is changed in edit mode of the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with JavaScript on the edit form, you can add a function called `PreSaveAction` which the form will always call. Inside of the function you can run any additional script you'd like, such as calculating a sum and updating another field on the item.

`PreSaveAction` *must* return `true` for the save to continue.

Comment: Thanks chris, do you have any referance that i can have a look at?

Comment: or even a forced postback when an item is changed in the edit mode. by edit mode i mean datasheet view. sorry i have updated the question

Comment: Ah, that's important. PreSaveAction only applies to the edit form.